# Need help to identify the actual date time format

Tags: postgresql, date, jpa, date-format

I have been struggling since few days to identify correct format for sample input date:
`2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000 +00:00:00`

Background : 
I am working on data migration with postgres. And, have identified that in DB, the datetime related fields like 'modifiedAt' have datatype as `varchar`, which is bit weird. These records have values in above mentioned format.

I have fixed it in new postgres DB instance with datatype as `timestamp`. After migrating data, these fields are showing datetime in following format:

`2020-01-30 14:39:25`

How can I format above date to give output in this dateformat `2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000 +00:00:00`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As the correct [Answer by Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65509993/642706) says, you are using the wrong data type. A moment, a specific point on the timeline, must be recorded in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. When submitting a value that includes time zone or offset-from-UTC, Postgres uses that zone to adjust to UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). Postgres then discards that accompanying zone/offset.

Answer (score 3):

First you want to use `timestamptz` not `timestamp`. `timestamptz` does not actually store the time zone, it just makes the value time zone aware. For more information on this see:

[Time Stamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps.

Second it looks like you did something like `timestamp(0)` which reduced the precision to whole seconds. If you leave the precision alone you get:

```
select '2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000 +00:00:00'::timestamptz;
         timestamptz         
-----------------------------
 01/30/2020 06:39:25.022 PST

-- I am in PST so the value gets rotated to that time zone for display.

-- If you want something closer to you desired output, then:

select to_char('2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000 +00:00:00'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.USOF');
            to_char            
-------------------------------
 2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000+00
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of timestamptz. Thanks for that. But, how can I print date or lets say `now()` to format : `2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000 +00:00:00`

Comment: Use the `to_char()` example I showed e.g. `select to_char(now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.USOF') ;`. For more info see [Data Formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: @ms_27 Why are you so concerned about the formatting of the text generated by the database to represent the stored `TIMESTAMP WIH TIME ZONE` value? That text is not what is stored. Postgres uses its own internal arrangement of bits to store the date-time value, which is not our business. And formatting a date-time value’s textual representation is the job of an app, not the database. Formatting output should be irrelevant to you data migration task.

Comment: Valid point @BasilBourque. I was thinking around exporting data to csv to validate that all the data is consistent post migration. And, I can simply achieve that by converting datetime from existing format to timestamp in both the DB's. :)

Comment: @ms_27 I see now, if you exported data from old and new databases, you could them run through a [diff tool](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools). That makes sense. In that case you would want the new database to emit data in the old format. I suggest you say this explicitly in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

While your timestamp strings do appear to have a time zone component, it is `+00`, which is the default for timestamps.  So, you might be able to just use `TO_TIMESTAMP` here with an appropriate format mask covering microseconds:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '2020-01-30 14:39:25.022123 +00:00:00'::text AS ts
)

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(LEFT(ts, 26), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The output value from the demo above is `2020-01-30 14:39:25.022123+00`

Comment: And, how to print date in format : `2020-01-30 14:39:25.022000 +00:00:00`

Comment: FYI, `+00` is not the default for timestamps, it just indicates that the timestamp is at `UTC`. It also indicates that it is a time zone aware timestamp versus a naive timestamp.